# Hbase calling HTable hangs

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

There is sample java code for Hbase connectivity program which is the famous "HbaseTest" class sample, which is available in the internet for long time.

I have compiled the code in my server and compiling was successful. When i run my Java class file, i am able to see that it is getting hanged in the particular line. "HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);"

It throws the below alert when running.

Jun 18, 2015 12:16:14 PM org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader WARNING: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable Jun 18, 2015 12:16:15 PM org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper INFO: The identifier of this process is pid@servername

I have identified it has stuck in that particular lines by giving Print statements.

Please do let me know what to do for the same. I have checked that the Hbase is running properly.

Kindly share your thoughts and idea's.

@hive @hbase @hadoop

Thanks in Advance Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem before it was network issues. Try setting retry and timeout parameters, e.g.

```
hbase.client.retries.number=2
zookeeper.session.timeout=2000
zookeeper.recovery.retry=0
hbase.rpc.timeout=100
ipc.socket.timeout=100
hbase.client.pause=100
zookeeper.recovery.retry.intervalmill=100
timeout=100
```

You may need to modify your network settings according to the errors that are thrown.